# How to check multiple input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know how to change my script to show correct feedback images when the user validates its answers.

My function has an array with correct answers and an empty array to store users answers.

When I validate, I need to show feedback image for the fields (if correct just show, if wrong show and replace feedback image with another one).

Here is my code:

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/usPMd/109/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            $("#validateButton").click(function schimbare() {
                $(".feedback").show();
                $('.feedback').attr('src', 'res/wrong.svg');
            });

        });


//verificam daca raspunsul este corect

function checkAnswer()
{
    var inputTF = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (i = 0; i < inputTF.length; i++)
    {
        if (inputTF[i].value == raspunsuri[i]){
            user.push(inputTF[i].value);
            $(".feedback").show();
        }
        else
        {
            user.push("");
            schimbare();

        }
        }

};
```

Comment: Show your HTML code and tell us what is exactly wrong.

Comment: @Yair Nevet fiddle its in edit now...Whats wrong? well...when i validate i would like to show feedback $(".feedback").hide(); that is hidden in init(); BUT only for correct answers...For wrong answers i need to call function schimbare(); which show and change image feedback $('.feedback').attr('src', 'res/wrong.svg');

Comment: Someone understood it?

Comment: To begin, element ids should be unique. You have 6 divs with id="box". Perhaps change this to be a class.

Comment: Done that,but this is not main problem :( the problem is how i show images for input with correct answers inserted and how i change wrong images for wrong answers inserted.Is there a function which change images from correct to wrong,but dont know how to make for to show them only for wrong answers

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript, you are defining an onClick handler for #validateButton. In your html, you have an onclick attribute on #validateButton which calls a different function. This is confusing. I would recommend removing both of these and defining a validate function, which will be responsible for rendering our correct/wrong images beside the input fields:

```
var validate = function () {
    $('input').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var answer = $this.attr('correct');
        var value = $this.val();
        var src = (answer === value) ? 'res/correct.svg' : 'res/wrong.svg';
        $this.closest('.box').find('img.feedback').attr('src', src);
    });
};
```

Now let's use jQuery to wire our validate method to the #validateButton click event:

```
$("#validateButton").on('click', validate);
```